# will some one tell me how to get remote notification i mean when sever post some thing user will get the notiffication

Tags: java, android

i search alot but i find a code which based on notification manager , it 
    just happens when user click , how can i make it in a proper way when 
     server uploads something user get notified

```
   public void shownotifications(View view) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
    notificBuilder.setContentText("Message");
    notificBuilder.setTicker("Alert New Message");
    notificBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);

    Intent moreInfoIntent = new Intent(this,MoreInfoNotification.class);
    TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    tStackBuilder.addParentStack(MoreInfoNotification.class);
    tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(moreInfoIntent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notifID,notificBuilder.build());
    isNotificActive = true;

}

public void stopnotifications(View view) {

    if(isNotificActive){
        notificationManager.cancel(notifID);

    }
}

public void alertnotifications(View view) {

    Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this,AlertReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alertTime,PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,alertIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have google `GCM` integrated on your server and your device.
You can go through [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) . 
Here is the Demo code from Google https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Comment: i did that today but i dont know proper way to get app id and client key

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion to you use [parse.com](https://parse.com/) notification sdk pushing notification on android mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but may be these [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) help you little bit.